# Need HEVC x.265 video encoder

Tags: open-source, video, media-converter

I would appreciate recommendations for a video encoder that will take all popular formats and convert them to HEVC x.265. I prefer cross-platform & open source but am absolutely willing to pay for the best program. My wish list:

- Convert any MKV/MP4/AVI input file to HEVC x.265
- Batch conversion for lots of files at once
- Make use of multiple threads (possibly nVidia GPU)
- Ability to set and remember preferred output format/bitrate
- Clear display of the the input video's specs
- Command-line option would be a nice bonus
- Would love if it calculates output based on settings
- Windows preferred, but Linux or Mac is okay

I want to test and standardize on a single configuration (HEVC, AAC, bitrate, color depth, etc) and then convert my entire library of mostly x.264.

Thanks

Comment: [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) (GUI and command line) and [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (command line) are the usually the most recommended programs for video encoding.

Comment: I tried FFmpeg and it gets the job done. Thanks for the suggestion.